# Cannot get access_token from reddit using web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, reddit

I would like to get an `access_token` from Reddit to use within my code, but keep getting this 401 error about an unsupported grant type. Here is the code (filtered the personal content):

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const FormData = require('form-data');
let data = new FormData()
data.append('code', 'temporary_code')
data.append('grant_type', "authorization_code")
data.append('redirect_uri', "http://localhost")
fetch('https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token', {
    method: 'post',
    body: data,
    headers: {'Authorization': `Basic ${Buffer.from('client_id:client_secret').toString('base64')}`, 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(console.log)
```

I constantly tried swapping out the values (mainly moving the `content-type` to different places) of my code. I even tried using `Postman` to make a post request, which also failed. I browsed the web (mainly reddit questions about the same problem, but with different app types or different programming languages) to try and get the answer. I even tried searching google multiple times for my problem, but all has failed. This is the Exact error I got:

```
{ message: 'Unauthorized', error: 401 }
```

While coding this, I was using the [`Reddit Wiki`](https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2) to make sure I was doing everything correctly. I noticed I had the `unsupported_grant_type` error, which eventually I gave up trying to fix myself. Now, I am asking you all to try and assist or even answer my problem. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Generally, a page served up from your own domain cannot access content from a different domain unless that target domain explicitly allows it.

Comment: I don't have any CORS errors because I am using Node.js. Forgot to mention that, sorry.

Comment: Ah, well that's a different story of course.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up. I was new to working with APIs, so of course I had no idea what I was doing. Thanks for your response. I will try my best next time to figure things out myself, before making a fool of myself and asking.